# remove .html extension from url with app.yaml in google app engine for java for static pages

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I am using Google app engine to serve static web pages but I want to remove .html extension in the URL. I created a App.yaml file. I created a folder called static with the app.yaml file included but it still does not work any ideas what I am doing wrong ?. I am using app engine with java.

```
 application: Google App Engine JSF 2.2 Template
 version: 1
 runtime: java

 handlers:
 - url: /(.+)
 mime_type: text/html
 static_files: static/\1.html
 upload: static/(.+)
```

Comment: Try `upload: static/\1.html`

Comment: Hey GAEfan I tried what you mention and it does not work

Comment: Well, that should work.  What you had was incorrect filename.  Is your app.yaml at the root level, and your `static` directory also at the root level?

Comment: I had the app.yaml in the static folder with the html files should it be outside.the static folder was in the war folder and the static html files and app.yaml file in static folder

Comment: yea.  changed to answer.

Comment: Hi GAEfan thank so much for the help so far I really appreciate it,I made the changes you mentioned but now I am getting this error   Unable to find property 'mime_type' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml$Handler

Comment: put mime_type last, after upload.  See updated answer

Comment: Hi GAEfan made the updates that you mentioned but now I have a new error. Unable to find property 'static_files' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml$Handler                                                                                                                                                        application: Google App Engine JSF 2.2 Template
   version: 1
   runtime: java

   handlers:
    - url: /(.+)
      static_files: static/\1.html
      upload: static/\1.html
      mime_type: text/html

Comment: Is your indenting as you see below?  the first line (with the -) is at the left.  The other 3 lines are indented 2 spaces (to match the other indenting in your app.yaml)

Comment: yes I followed your instructions and this is my error now  Unable to find property 'static_files' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml$Handler

Comment: Can you show exactly what you have in your app.yaml, with proper indentations?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 - url: /(.+)
   file: static/\1.html
```

and put app.yaml at the root (war folder).  And, make sure the indentation is as you see here.  Your indentation is incorrect.  Should be 2 spaces indented, except the `- url` line.

Comment: What is the `\1` for? How can it be done with GAE Java?

Answer (score 0):

Hey GAEfan here is my code with the indent and it is google app engine for java,thanks again for the help

```
  application: Google App Engine JSF 2.2 Template
  version: 1
  runtime: java

  handlers:
  - url: /(.+)
    static_files: static/\1.html
    upload: static/\1.html
    mime_type: text/html
```

Comment: OK, `static_files` is for another use in java. Try revised answer.